# Efficiently load large batch of OneToMany collections at once with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a `Parent` entity with a `@OneToMany` relationship with a `Child` entity. Most of the time, when I need to work with a `Parent`’s `Child` entities, I’m working with a single parent, so lazy fetching (`FetchMode.SELECT`) is appropriate.

However, I have a situation where I’m querying a large number of `Parent`s (sometimes hundreds or even thousands), and I need to work with their `Child` entities. `FetchMode.SELECT` gives me a serious N+1 problem, so I need to do something different in this scenario. If I were doing this via JDBC, it’d be single query for the `Parent` records, then another query for all the `Child` records using an `IN` statement (`where child.parentid in (?,?,?....)`). I need live Hibernate entities, because Hibernate Search is going to call getChildren() as part of its indexing process.

The options I’ve considered are:

1. `Criteria.setFetchMode(“children”, FetchMode.JOIN)` (or `join fetch` in HQL) - this would give me a cartesian product, though, which is brutal with that many entities.
2. Adding `@BatchSize` to `Parent.getChildren()` - this would help for my big batch scenario, but it isn’t really the strategy I want to use for normal operations. It’d be perfect if I could set a batch size for the fetch in my Criteria/HQL, but I can’t find a way to do so.
3. Using `FetchMode.SUBSELECT` in `Parent.getChildren()` - much like `@BatchSize`, this would be great for my big batch scenario, but isn’t appropriate for normal operations, and I can’t find a way to use it with Criteria/HQL (Criteria and the entity annotations use different FetchMode enums, despite the duplicate name).

tldr; I have a one-to-many relationship with a lazy fetch mode, but sometimes I want to be able to efficiently load the relationship for many entities at once.

Comment: 1. I don't see what prevents you from doing the same IN query with JPA than the one you would do with JDBC; 2. I don't see why the cartesian product would be so brutal. Suppose you have 500 parents each with 10 children, the IN query would load 5000 rows, and the join fetch query would load... 5000 rows.

Comment: 1. Hibernate Search needs Parent.getChildren() to container the child records, which is why I can't just do a separate query for the children. I've updated the question to clarify this.  2. The problem isn't the number of rows, it's retrieving all the data for the same Parent multiple times (it has a non-trivial number of columns)

Comment: IMHO when the query result sizes become even modestly large and/or the query becomes even modestly complex, I just use a native query via `createNativeQuery()` and be done with it. Hibernate is convenient to use, but can quickly become inefficient.

Comment: Hah, I feel the same way. Sadly, we're indexing with Hibernate Search, and I need to send it real Parent entities, and it's going to call getChildren(). So I need a way to efficiently populate that relationship or I'll be in "N+1 Land" (Disney World's least popular park)